# How can we extend the predictive interface so it can suggest new operations?

Tags: front-end, interface, undocumented

#### Introduction

Mathematica 9 has introduced a new [predictive interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html).  For each output, it suggest possible actions the user might want to take.

[image: The predictive interface at work]

**How can this interface be extended so that it will suggest additional, possibly user-defined, actions?**

---

#### The starting point

@Rojo [mentioned in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7324943#7324943) that he discovered that much of the functionality is contained in the `` Predictions` ``  and `` PredictiveInterface` ``  contexts.  Many of the symbols have usage messages (but make sure that you trigger loading them by using the predictive interface at least once).

The `` Predictions`PredictionRule `` symbol seems to contain the rules on which the predictions are based, as downvalues (see its usage message).

The functionality seems to be defined in files found in the `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Applications/PredictiveInterface/` directory.  The relevant part is in `.mx` files (not directly readable) and comments in the `.m` files suggest that these may be updated automatically.

I posted this question as a starting point for people who want to figure out how this works, and to facilitate collaboration.

Comment: Is this the same question as [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-suggestions-bar)?

Comment: @Leonid Oops... I guess I'll delete this soon and transfer the info to the other Q

Comment: @Leonid Actually, after looking at that question, I would suggest implementing a separate suggestion bar to the OP.  Shall we keep this question as specific to the built-in predictive interface and keep the other one separate?

Comment: Perhaps it is a good idea. I was not sure whether or not yours is a dupe, from the start. Let's see what others think.

Comment: I thought it worth pointing out that the (relatively new) answer in the @LeonidShifrin's linked question actually solves this issue.

Comment: @b3m2a1 OK, you can vote to close.