# How to extend the suggestions bar?

Tags: predictive-interface

I'm looking for a way to *modify and/or customize* the predictive interface:

[image]

**Here are some customizations that I'd like to make:**

- If a cell evaluates to a list, I'd like to see the length and dimensions displayed
- Always display the absolute timing of the above cell's computation
- Add a button to copy the above input cell into a new code cell
- Add a button to copy the above input to the clipboard as plaintext

  *And many more...*

Is there any way to accomplish this by modifying the existing interface or adding a totally new bar? Most pro-users disable and forget about it, but if we could change the contents of the bar it would become more useful.

**What I've tried:**

Nothing, I've no idea where to start.

Comment: A older question that contemplates adding more predictions to the bar can be found at [Is it possible to customize the Suggestions Bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16562/142).

Comment: @WReach thanks, I didn’t see that question - and it has a good answer but for very Quantity-specific things, it doesn’t ask/explain how to do these other types of things (like auto-timing). I am hoping there might be a more recent and general answer out there...